# Summary in statistics in Stata containing different ratios

Tags: stata, summary

I have a dataset and I want to calculate summary statistics for different variables of the dataset. I want to display the mean, coefficient of variation and the ratios of 75% quantile / 25% quantile, 95% quantile / 5% quantile and 2nd highest/ 2nd lowest value. I'm new to Stata and managed to get a table containing the quantiles, but not the ratios.

Comment: This is a marginal question for SO, as it lacks a reproducible example and any code attempt whatsoever. SO is not a code-writing service. You should at least show how far you got.

Answer (score 2):

Most but not all of those measures are easy given results accessible after `summarize, detail`.

Here is one approach:

```
program mysummary, rclass sortpreserve 
    syntax varname(numeric) [if] [in]
    marksample touse 
    quietly replace `touse' = -`touse'
    quietly su `varlist' if `touse', detail 
    return scalar mean = r(mean)
    return scalar cv = r(sd) / r(mean)
    return scalar ratio25 = r(p75) / r(p25)
    return scalar ratio5 = r(p95) / r(p5)
    local N = r(N)
    sort `touse' `varlist'
    return scalar ratio2nd = `varlist'[`N'-1] / `varlist'[2] 
end 

sysuse auto, clear 

tempname handle
postfile `handle' str32 varname mean cv ratio25 ratio5 ratio2nd using myresults, replace 

ds, has(type numeric) 

foreach v in `r(varlist)' { 
    mysummary `v'
    post `handle' ("`v'") (r(mean)) (r(cv)) (r(ratio25)) (r(ratio5)) (r(ratio2nd))
}

postclose `handle'

use myresults 
format mean-ratio2nd %4.3f 

list, sep(0) noobs 

  +---------------------------------------------------------------+
  |      varname       mean      cv   ratio25   ratio5   ratio2nd |
  |---------------------------------------------------------------|
  |        price   6165.257   0.478     1.512    3.593      4.395 |
  |          mpg     21.297   0.272     1.389    2.429      2.917 |
  |        rep78      3.406   0.291     1.333    2.500      5.000 |
  |     headroom      2.993   0.283     1.400    3.000      3.000 |
  |        trunk     13.757   0.311     1.700    3.000      3.667 |
  |       weight   3019.459   0.257     1.607    2.344      2.622 |
  |       length    187.932   0.118     1.200    1.435      1.565 |
  |         turn     39.649   0.111     1.194    1.394      1.500 |
  | displacement    197.297   0.465     2.101    4.070      4.706 |
  |   gear_ratio      3.015   0.151     1.234    1.658      1.701 |
  |      foreign      0.297   1.548         .        .          . |
  +---------------------------------------------------------------+
```

The missings in the last row arise because for this indicator variable, the three ratios concerned imply dividing by 0, which is the lower quartile, the 5% percentile and the second lowest value. Statistically you are unlikely to care about such variables in this context.